# Browser doesn't load CSS with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

Tags: javascript, css, cross-domain

I am trying to load a CSS and a Javascript file from cross origin. I have also set the header   `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response but the browser doesn't load the files, I load the CSS using the code given below:

```
var fileref = document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

i want to load css and js using http connection which will be loaded in https :// [site]

Comment: What is `filename`, and what makes you think that header controls whether a browser loads a stylesheet?

Comment: filename is url . header means http header like  Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); %>

Comment: Do you have any console output for us (Firefox `Ctrl-K`, Chrome `Ctrl-Shift-J`, IIRC)? Are you sure the loaded files are not faulty?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/css/style.css

Comment: Why are you loading something from localhost...?

Comment: ya i tried with in the same domain it works.

Comment: yes i load css from local host but from different application

Comment: i am trying to develop extension for chrome browser . and i am trying to load css and js.

Comment: [blocked] The page at [url] ran insecure content from http://localhost:8080/mystyle.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `filename` variable has the correct path with `http://` as part of it.  Example: `http://localhost:8080/css/style.css`  or  `http://localhost:8080/project_folder/css/style.css`

Comment: yes it has,it don't show it in stackoverflow , i am new user i dont know how to use

Comment: What happens if you try to copy and paste the same path in the Browser itself?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? This should work no problem - I just tried it on my localhost and it works just fine. Are you sure that there isn't other code that is involved?

Comment: no it does not display any error but it blocked the file i want to load for example [blocked] The page at [URL] ran insecure content from http://localhost:8080/style.aspx.

Comment: is there any problem if i use cross origin resouce with https ?

Comment: I am not sure, but you could try to take out the http or https and instead use the following: "//localhost:8080/css/style.css". By only having the 2 slashes in front of the resource path, you leave it up to the Browser to decide the protocol

Comment: Maybe this will help - directly quoted from the Chrome extension docs (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html):                                                   "If an extension wants both secure and non-secure HTTP access to a given host or set of hosts, it must declare the permissions separately: `"permissions": [
  http://www.google.com/,
  https://www.google.com/
]`
"